# How can I use jQuery to change the class of a DIV inside an A element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<a id="menuPrev">
<div class="sprite-contol-double-180"></div>
</a>
```

Is there a way that I can use jQuery to change the class to "sprite-blank"

Comment: Please search online before asking on SO. This is a VERY TRIVIAL TASK using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this code:

```
$("#menuPrev > div").attr("class","sprite-blank");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#menuPrev > div').removeClass('sprite-contol-double-180').addClass('sprite-blank');
```